# error in sending email on button click in asp.net c#

Tags: c#

I am using visual studio 2012 and asp.net framework 4.5. I want to create a form that whenever the user clicks the submit button an email be should be sent to me. I am using google smtp settings in my coding but I get an error like this "Failure Sending mail". I am pasting my coding for reference

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {   
    MailMessage mailmessage = new MailMessage()
    {
        Subject = txtName.Text.ToString().Trim(),
        Body = txtComment.Text.ToString().Trim(),
        IsBodyHtml = false
    };

    mailmessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(Label1.Text));
    mailmessage.To.Add("myusername.com");
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    smtpClient.SendAsync(mailmessage, null);

    Response.Write("Your mail has been sent successfuly");
    Label1.Text = "Your mail has been successfully sent..!!";
    this.txtComment.Text = "";
    this.txtName.Text = "";
```

web config file

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="myusername.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com"
     port="465" 
     userName=""
     password=""
     enableSsl="true"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

I have tried the port as 587 but I get the same error.

Comment: Where did you add the credentials?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername.com", "pwd"),
            EnableSsl = true
        };
        client.Send("myusername.com", "myusername.com", "test", "testbody");
    }

Comment: Do u mean the above credentials??

Answer (score 0):

As somebody already suggested, try checking the Smtp Client credentials before sending the mail. Also i had some problems in the past with `SmtpClient.SendAsync`. Try to use `SmtpClient.Send` instead. Otherwise i see really no problem in your code.

Edit: It seems you created 2 SmtpClients. One in page load and one in buttonClick method. Does the second one know the credentials too?

Comment: In smtpclient.send I get an error as No overload method. It requires 2 arguments

Comment: Are you really sure? Check this for more info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: can u explain me in detail which coding to keep. I pasted the 2 coding. one on button click and another in web config file. do I need to type the credential coding in page load event.

Comment: I did not create a client in page load event. I created in web config file and in button click event. in button click event only an instance is created. SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

Comment: should I paste my coding again?

Comment: They look nearly the same but only with 2 differences i said. Credentials are crucial in your case. Either add them to the buttonClick or rewrite whole client as in PageLoad. PageLoad one seems to be okay. Tried it right now and it works with my custom arguments. Edit : var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587) -> this is in your PageLoad method so you created a client there.

Comment: ok as u explained an smtp client is created in page load event but the question is If I create the client in page load then do I need to create a client in web config file?? I am just confused where and where coding to keep in page load with web config or page load and button click or to keep all the three coding

Comment: No. But you need the information that is in web config file to actually use Smtp. But it doesnt have to be there. You can place the information like credentials right into your code. Everything you used in webconfig can also be set directly in code.

Comment: If I keep the credentials in web config and the coding on button click or keep the coding in button click event and page load event I get the same error. mail sending failed. pls help

Comment: Is there no inner exception thrown? as to why sending failed?

Comment: I just get an exception on this line smtpClient.SendAsync(mailmessage, null);

Comment: Alright then. Its too bad i cant help you more as i dont know why it does that. Altough if the exception is thrown there, it may be possible that you have wrong authentication or the smtp server is currently down. Some other thoughts - try to tinker with SmtpClient.EnableSsl property. There is also a possibility that your firewall is blocking port you want to use. I hope something on the list will work. Im afraid i have ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Your Email">
      <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="Your Email" password="Your Password"></network>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Try above code in web config

Comment: I tried the coding in web config file. I am getting the error on the line smtpClient.SendAsync(mailmessage, null); as faliure sending email